# Networkx - create graphs from communities

Tags: python, networkx

With the following working code:

```
import netowkx as nx
import networkx.algorithms.community as nx_comm

G = nx.karate_club_graph()

# Find the communities
communities = sorted(nx_comm.greedy_modularity_communities(G), key=len, reverse=True)
# Count the communities
print(f"The club has {len(communities)} communities.")

'''Add community to node attributes'''
for c, v_c in enumerate(communities):
    for v in v_c:
        # Add 1 to save 0 for external edges
        G.nodes[v]['community'] = c + 1
        

'''Find internal edges and add their community to their attributes'''
for v, w, in G.edges:
    if G.nodes[v]['community'] == G.nodes[w]['community']:
        # Internal edge, mark with community
        G.edges[v, w]['community'] = G.nodes[v]['community']
    else:
        # External edge, mark as 0
        G.edges[v, w]['community'] = 0
```

How do I end up with `n` new Graphs (or subgraphs), one object (described as "Graph with n nodes and w edges"
)for each community?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a similar approach than the one taken in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43829001/how-to-create-a-subgraph-by-using-edges-attributes). First, you can create one graph for each of your communities. You can then identify the edges you want to add to each graph with `[(u,v,d) for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True) if d['community'] == i+1])`.

This is what the code looks like:

```py
import networkx as nx
import networkx.algorithms.community as nx_comm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.karate_club_graph()

# Find the communities
communities = sorted(nx_comm.greedy_modularity_communities(G), key=len, reverse=True)

# Count the communities
print(f"The club has {len(communities)} communities.")

'''Add community to node attributes'''
for c, v_c in enumerate(communities):
    for v in v_c:
        # Add 1 to save 0 for external edges
        G.nodes[v]['community'] = c + 1

'''Find internal edges and add their community to their attributes'''
for v, w, in G.edges:
    if G.nodes[v]['community'] == G.nodes[w]['community']:
        # Internal edge, mark with community
        G.edges[v, w]['community'] = G.nodes[v]['community']
    else:
        # External edge, mark as 0
        G.edges[v, w]['community'] = 0



N_coms=len(communities)
edges_coms=[]#edge list for each community
coms_G=[nx.Graph() for _ in range(N_coms)] #community graphs
colors=['tab:blue','tab:orange','tab:green']
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))

for i in range(N_coms):
  edges_coms.append([(u,v,d) for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True) if d['community'] == i+1])#identify edges of interest using the edge attribute
  coms_G[i].add_edges_from(edges_coms[i]) #add edges
  plt.subplot(1,3,i+1)#plot communities
  plt.title('Community '+str(i+1))
  pos = nx.circular_layout(coms_G[i])
  nx.draw(coms_G[i],pos=pos,with_labels=True,node_color=colors[i])
```

And the output gives:

[image]